# How to run a function for each element in a list on a different thread sequentially and update the (passive) view after each function has run?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a WinForm [«Passive View»](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) and a «Controller» where the controller is running a long running function for each element in a list.

I want the following:

- The functions shall run sequentially
- The view mustn't freeze while looping the list and running the functions
- After each function has run, the view shall be updated with the result of the run

The (single-threaded) code looks like this as of now:

```
View.DateSpan.Workdays.ForEach( 
   d => {
           var processRunInfo = _processRunner.Run( configFile, d );

           UdateViewFrom( processRunInfo );
         } );
```

The code above "works" but causes the view to freeze since it uses the very same thread, and it updates the view batch-wise.

`Workdays` is an `IEnumerable<DateTime>`, and `ForEach` does what `ForEach` of `List<T>` does but is an extension method from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

`_processRunner.Run` runs an external command line application with the arguments supplied.

Comment: Yes, WinForm (stated in the first sentence of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to Nenad and Bastiaan for pointing me in the `Control.Invoke` direction.

In order to fully reap the benefits of the «passive view» pattern, I don't want any knowledge of the `Control` type of WinForms in the «[supervising controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html)» (that type should only be known by the implementer of the view interface, i.e. the one derived from `Form`).

Here's how I solved the issue satisfactory:

- The controller creates a new `Thread` instance with the `ForEach` loop a an argument, and then starts the created instance.

Before:

```
View.DateSpan.Workdays.ForEach(d =>
                                  {
                                     // do stuff...
                                  } );
```

After:

```
new Thread( () => View.DateSpan.Workdays.ForEach( d =>
                                                     {
                                                        // do stuff...
                                                     } ) ).Start();
```

- The view's widget update methods use a helper method that checks if the request comes from another thread, and if so uses `Invoke`. See the code below.

Before:

```
public string Status
{
  set { _statusLabel.Text = value ); }
}
```

After:

```
public string Status
{
  set { ExecuteOnUIThread( _statusLabel, () => _statusLabel.Text = value ); }
}
```

The helper method:

```
private static void ExecuteOnUIThread( Control control, Action action )
{
    if ( control.InvokeRequired )
    {
       control.Invoke( action );
    }
    else
    {
       action();
    }
 }
```

The production WinForm view works like a charm, and with the addition of a while loop that spins the thread while the background thread does its work in my BDD stories, so do they with my old view «[test spy](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Spy.html)».

Answer (score 1):

Running the foreach loop in a separate thread with a callback to the Invoke of your control (form) would be my solution.

The link below contains a decent example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Comment: Is this going to work for webforms? I would have thought its not going to find the parent window handle since its a process running on the server.

Comment: As stated in the question; the «passive view» is a WinForm.

Answer (score 1):

You should make long-running calculation in the separate thread (not the main GUI thread), so that main thread that have message loop can be free.
Than, inside of for-each loop, you should marshal UpdateViewForm method to the GUI thread using [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method. You can choose to wrap methods in PassiveView, like this:

```
public void DoSomething() {
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(DoSomethingDelegate);
        ...
    }
}
```

or just, instead of standard method invocation, use something like this:

```
myFormControl1.Invoke(myFormControl1.myDelegate);
```

Comment: As stated in the question, the view is a «Passive View» [Fowler], and hence isn't able to invoke anything (it raises a few events, and implements a few properties and methods).

In other words, I need the controller to take responsibility for this one.

Comment: You said that Passive View is a WinForm. Hence, it is inherited from Control, so it has Invoke method, which can marshal execution from any thread to GUI thread. Controller can set a property of a View, which is wrapped as I showed you before, and it will 'transfer' an execution from a calling thread to GUI thread. I assumed here that Controller thread is not a GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to take advantage of PLINQ - Parallel Linq

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx

And you could do something like

```
View.DateSpan.Workdays.AsParallel().ForEach( 
   d => {
           var processRunInfo = _processRunner.Run( configFile, d );

           UdateViewFrom( processRunInfo );
         } );
```

You would still most likely have to handle the return update in a callback event.

Comment: I've never used PLINQ and doesn't know about its details. However, the name suggests that its *parallel*.

In other words; I'm afraid that your code sample will run each closure of the ForEach in parallel.

Is that the case?

Comment: It should be based on per enclosure yes, so it's possible that it might work natively with no need for callbacks. The goal of it is to make working with parallel processing the least amount of as possible. I also believe that it offers OrderedParallel types that will ascertain the order of operations is sequential if sequence matters.